# Get rid of line beneath bars using hist() in R

Tags: r

I am using the following code if it helpful to plot some data using `hist()` in R.

```
hist(info$data, breaks=300, main="Some Data", xlab="data", xlim=c(0, 10000))
```

And this is the image I get the following image:
[image: Plot of data]

Is there a way to get rid of the line at y=0 that is underlining all of the bars? Or is there some better way to extend it to the y axis so it looks more like an axis rather than just some line beneath my bars?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but maybe it satisfies your needs... `hist(info$data, breaks=300, main="Some Data", xlab="data", xlim=c(0, 10000), border = NA, col = "black")`. The line at y=0 is the border of the empty bars, so you can just remove the border completely and then color in the bars.

Comment: Why not include a reproducible example?

Comment: @Laterow thats helpful, it does get rid of that line.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I could include data but any set of numbers plotted with hist() gives that line for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(info, aes(x=data)) + geom_histogram(binwidth) +
  ggtitle("Some Data") + xlab("data") + xlim(0,10000)
```

Comment: the problem is solved with `yaxs='i'` and/or `xaxs='i'`, can't you provide a solution to the problem at hand before introducing something completely different?